# How can disable inheritance in tailwind?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

i use tailwind-css for styling my components in Nuxtjs
and my components .

and this is my style classes

```
.ccard {
  @apply bg-white px-2 py-10;
  &-header {
    @apply relative;
    &-btn {
      @apply btn btn-circle btn-sm  btn-primary px-0 border-0;
    }
    &-img {
      // width: 100%;
      // height: 100%;
      @apply object-cover  w-full;
    }
  }
  &-detail {
    @apply text-center pt-2 px-1;
    &-cat {
      @apply text-sm text-gray-400 mb-2;
    }
    &-title {
      @apply text-lg font-semibold;
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my component template

```html
<template>
  <div class="ccard">
    <div class="ccard-header">
      <button class="ccard-header-btn">
        <magnify />
      </button>
      <img :src="data.src" class="ccard-header-img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ccard-detail">
      <div class="ccard-detail-cat">{{ data.cat }}</div>
      <div class="ccard-detail-title">{{ data.title }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and this is result
[image]
i expect the button to be a circle BUT it is not !
i got inspect and it inhertited a min-height from some-where i dont know where it is .
and i think in tailwind child tags inherit their parent tags classes and i think this is not good .

how can i disable heritance in tailwind-css

Answer (score 0):

I think the inheritance in 'tailwind-css' isn't your problem. I have two answers to this question:

1)you have to check to magnify inside the btn, maybe it has a little x-margin or x-padding

2)you have to set specific width and height (w-10 h-10) classes in the icon.

look at this code:

```
  <button class="bg-green-400 rounded-full">
    <img class="w-10 h-10 p-2" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/000000/search--v1.png"/>
  </button>
```